# Combine Multiple Columns into one with same amount of Rows

Tags: python, pandas

I'm scraping prices off a website using part numbers.
The logic is:

1. a list of part numbers is inputted
2. a price will be returned for each part from the database on the website
3. The part belongs to one of the five companies, so 5 different lists are generated.

For example below is the initial list of part numbers (input):
b123
nadsf
ower
weoa

they each belong to a company, :

```
Part #     Company A        B          C          D
b123          1.5
nadsf                      3.4
ower                                             47
weoa                                  33
```

The output in csv right now is:

```
    0
0   1.5   
1   0     
2   0
3   0
0   0     
1   3.4   
2   0
3   0
0   0     
1   0     
2   33
3   0
0   0     
1   0     
2   0
3   47
0   0     
1   0     
2   0
3   0
```

I only want one list instead of 5; the desired output is:

```
0    1.5

1    3.4

2    33

3    47
```

Not sure how I can do this,

Any help/suggestions appreciated!

Please see below for my code:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\212677036\Documents\Copy of MIC Parts Review.xlsx')
PN = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=['Product code'])

i = 0

Total_rows = PN.shape[0]
partnumlist = []
partnumlist1 = []
partnumlist2 = []
partnumlist3 = []
partnumlist4 = []
partnumlist5 = []

while i < Total_rows:

         data = {"partOptionFilter": {"PartNumber": PN.iloc[i, 0], "AlternativeOemId": "17155"}}
         r = requests.post('https://www.partsfinder.com/Catalog/Service/GetPartOptions', json=data).json()

         partnumlist.append(r['Data']['PartOptions'][0]['YourPrice'])

         data1 = {"partOptionFilter": {"PartNumber": PN.iloc[i, 0], "AlternativeOemId": "17475"}}
         r1 = requests.post('https://www.partsfinder.com/Catalog/Service/GetPartOptions', json=data1).json()

         partnumlist1.append(r1['Data']['PartOptions'][0]['YourPrice'])

         data2 = {"partOptionFilter": {"PartNumber": PN.iloc[i, 0], "AlternativeOemId": "16880"}}
         r2 = requests.post('https://www.partsfinder.com/Catalog/Service/GetPartOptions', json=data2).json()

         partnumlist2.append(r2['Data']['PartOptions'][0]['YourPrice'])

         data3 = {"partOptionFilter": {"PartNumber": PN.iloc[i, 0], "AlternativeOemId": "47221"}}
         r3 = requests.post('https://www.partsfinder.com/Catalog/Service/GetPartOptions', json=data3).json()

         partnumlist3.append(r3['Data']['PartOptions'][0]['YourPrice'])

         data4 = {"partOptionFilter": {"PartNumber": PN.iloc[i, 0], "AlternativeOemId": "17045"}}
         r4 = requests.post('https://www.partsfinder.com/Catalog/Service/GetPartOptions', json=data4).json()

         partnumlist4.append(r4['Data']['PartOptions'][0]['YourPrice'])

         data5 = {"partOptionFilter": {"PartNumber": PN.iloc[i, 0], "AlternativeOemId": "17055"}}
         r5 = requests.post('https://www.partsfinder.com/Catalog/Service/GetPartOptions', json=data5).json()

         partnumlist5.append(r5['Data']['PartOptions'][0]['YourPrice'])

         i=i+1

list_of_dataframes = [pd.DataFrame(partnumlist),pd.DataFrame(partnumlist1),
               pd.DataFrame(partnumlist2), pd.DataFrame(partnumlist3),
               pd.DataFrame(partnumlist4), pd.DataFrame(partnumlist5)]

pd.concat(list_of_dataframes).to_csv(r'C:\Users\212677036\Documents\output25.csv')
```

Comment: You could make a dataframe with the columns `['Part', 'Company', 'value']`

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the current CSV output you're getting follows this pattern of 0s in it. You can apply a simple filtering operation on your output CSV or the data frame that you're saving as the CSV.

For example, your output CSV is converted to a Dataframe df.

df = pd.concat(list_of_dataframes) #assuming this is your output csv dataframe

I do not see a column name for the df. You can probably add a column name to the second column with 0s of your choice. Once you have that,

df = df[~(df['col'] == 0])]

This would remove all the rows with 0s in the second column (because of the ~) and give you the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Boolean indexing to remove all zero values and reset the index so that it will count from 0 to N-1. You will have to save the result
of `pd.concat` to a variable before saving it to a cvs. You can do it like so:

```
concatenated = pd.concat(list_of_dataframes)
clean = concatenated[concatenated[0] != 0].reset_index(drop=True)
clean.to_csv(r'C:\Users\212677036\Documents\output25.csv')
```

This should give you the desired output:

```
0    1.5
1    3.4
2    33
3    47
```

Just to provide additional insight, the `0` in the first row of your output csv file is the column name of your DataFrame. Pandas defaults to using a range index of `0..M` (M = # of columns) when you don't provide it to the DataFrame constructor.

Therefore, `concatenated[0]` selects the first column in your DataFrame, and `concatenated[0] == 0` checks whether each value in your column is equal to `0`, resulting in a Series of `True` or `False` values, which can then be used to selectively index your data.